# distance between the mean of points vs the distance between a random point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given $M$ points $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_M\in \mathbb R^N$. Let $\bar x$ denote the center(mean) of those $M$ points. Let $y$ be a random point. I am trying to prove 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^M|x_i-y|^2 - \sum_{i=1}^M |x_i-\bar x|^2 = M|\bar x-y|^2
$$
where by $|x-y|$ we mean the Euclidean distance.

Any suggestions for a quick proof?

Comment: What is $s$? Is it $y$?

Comment: @mathlove yes sure. corrected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 
$$A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)$$
we have

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{M}|x_i-y|^2-\sum_{i=1}^{M}|x_i-\bar x|^2&=\sum_{i=1}^{M}((x_i-y)+(x_i-\bar x))((x_i-y)-(x_i-\bar x))\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{M}(2x_i-y-\bar x)(\bar x-y)\\&=(\bar x-y)\sum_{i=1}^{M}(2x_i-y-\bar x)\\&=(\bar x-y)\left(2M\bar x-My-M\bar x\right)\\&=M(\bar x-y)(\bar x-y)\\&=M|\bar x-y|^2\end{align}$$